# Any canon Shadowrun material related to NY/PA/NJ areas?

Tags: campaign-settings, shadowrun-sr4

I'm looking for specific, *canon* (i.e. official, published) references to material for the Shadowrun game-world setting. My game setting is based around the Philadelphia area; I've turned New Jersey into a radioactive swamp, then dropped a nuke in it; I've got some things established for the Philly area, and NYC.

What I want to know is whether anyone knows of specific references to published material dealing with this region. Any mention of the big apple in Shadowrun's history? Any famous names in the area, or megacorps that are mentioned? Anything at all that's part of the published SR work, that I can incorporate, or at least avoid contradicting.

If you have any home-brewed material for that area, I would love to see a link in comments, but please don't put it as an answer. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current [Shadowrun Missions](http://www.shadowrun4.com/missions/index.shtml) are set in New York City. Catalyst Game Labs has published a 32 page PDF guide, [Shadowrun: The Rotten Apple: Manhatten](http://www.battlecorps.com/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=28_187_212&products_id=2252), which is available for sale from their web store for $3.95. There are [nine adventures](http://www.battlecorps.com/catalog/index.php?cPath=28_187_215) available also on the web store. The first one, [SRM00 Everyone's your Friend](http://www.battlecorps.com/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=28_187_215&products_id=2253) is free. All of the others are $3.95.

Answer (score 3):

The [Shadowrun Almanac](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934857823) contains information about a WHOLE Lot of places...

Answer (score 3):

The SR 1st edition supplement [*Neo-Anarchist's Guide to North America*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/51555/the-neo-anarchists-the-guide-to-north-america) had quite a bit about New York City itself.

Answer (score 2):

[Shadows of North America](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=3321&it=1&filters=0_0_0_1700) has a little blurb about NYC as well, basically the same as the Shadowrun Missions setting mentioned by Eric above.  There's a brief mention of Philadelphia as being a city in the "Northeast Corridor" but no details.