# What's in Manhattan in 2071?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, campaign-settings

Most of Shadowrun settings center on Seattle and the Western Seaboard.  Are there any, perhaps unofficial or older, sources for how other megatropolises such as Manhattan and FDC developed after the Awakening?  Major corps, notable gangs and movements, anything?

Comment: I believe this is covered already by this question's answers: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/672/any-canon-shadowrun-material-related-to-ny-pa-nj-areas

Comment: Actually, not a duplicate, as those answers cover before 2071, i.e. 5th edition.

Comment: @wraith808 5th edition is in 2075

Answer (score 1):

As you are mentioning SR4, you will find a lot of details on the [Shadowrun wikia page](http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/New_York_City).

Additionally, a friend has done the following map of Manhattan in the 2070's, that you will find [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97497952/Shadowrun/Shadowrun%20-%20Carte%20New%20York%20termin%C3%A9e.png).